# How to send OS logs and container logs from AWS EKS to Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

My understanding is that the Cloudwatch agent is available both as a Linux binary and as a Kubernetes deamonset.

I am aware that the EKS container logs could be forwarded to Cloudwatch using the cloudwatch agent that runs as EKS daemonset.

I have a query on how to send OS logs from EKS nodes to cloudwatch? Would the cloudwatch agent daemonset service be able to send the OS logs to Cloudwatch? or is the Linux binary required to be run on the EKS nodes to send OS logs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that either can be used independently.

You can set up [Fluentd or Fluent Bit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-logs-FluentBit.html) as a DaemonSet to send logs to CloudWatch Logs.

Alternatively, you can install [CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/implementing-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch/kubernetes-eks-logging.html) on Amazon EKS nodes using Distributor and State Manager.  You may also consider including it in the [launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html) to automate installation because the EKS-optimized AMI does not include the agent by default.